# Biztalk ESB itinerary combine data source

Tags: biztalk, esb

I am struggling to transfer my data in my itinerary in my Biztalk ESB solution, I'm using Message-based instead of Orchestration. My itinerary scenario in Biztalk ESB is:

1. Receive request CreatePayment with 2 parameters: Claim Object and
   Payment Object
2. Send Claim Object to external service to Verify Claim
3. Receive result from step 2, then combine the result with Payment Object in request at step 1, then send it to external service to Create Task

My problem is at step 3, I don't know how to combine data from 2 resources. Is there any knowledge that I missing in Biztalk ESB. I just started learning Biztalk for a few weeks. Now I got trouble and I really wait for feedback from you.

Sorry I have to post my itinerary picture to OneDrive since I cannot post it to this: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=584F1A7DD6FCBF77!961&authkey=!ANQVuaTflyExPTo&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG

Answer (score 1):

If you can switch to Orchestration, then setting some unique fields as correlationId will solve your problem.

If you are limited to use Message-based instead of Orchestration. below is 2 possible approach you may try.

1. If you can control the external service, change it to accept your payment object and return it as-is in its response.
2. If you cannot change the external service, what you can do is wrap the service such as an external assembly. then call this service in a mapping using script functoid.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems like that of an Enrichment Scenario.
Check out the sample provided in ESB Toolkit samples:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/esb-toolkit/installing-and-running-the-message-enrichment-sample

You will have to use an Orchestration extender in your itinerary.